# Thread's copy of local variable

Tags: java, multithreading

Threads have separate copy of local variables. I have a method in which a hashtable object is created. Will there be two different copies of hashtable objects for two different threads ?. the hashtable object is then passed to other method.

example method:

```
public void exampleMethod(String a,String b, String c)
{

   final Hashtable<String,String> parameterMap=new Hashtable<String,String>();
   parameterMap.put("key1",a);
   parameterMap.put("key2",b);
   parameterMap.put("key3",c);

   pqrsObject.takeRequest(parameterMap);

}
```

Comment: a hashtable is a local variable just like any other - you answered the question your self...

Comment: As long this code, yes there will be new instances every time you are calling exampleMethod. If other parts in the code (takeRequest() assign the refernce to a variable that can be accessed from diferent threads is not clear. But it seems it is not the case.

Comment: yes it will be unless you are calling pqrsObject.takeRequest just once and multiple threads accessing/modifying your hash map in same pqrsObject object.

Answer (score 2):

The `hashtable` in your example is a local variable and will be created for every call to the method.

that is because every time you call your function the line

```
final Hashtable<String,String> parameterMap=new Hashtable<String,String>();
```

is called, creating a new `hashtable` and placing it in `parameterMap`. i don't know what you need the `hashtable` for, but if you need it outside the method you might want to create it on a class of in other ways

now to your question:

> Threads have separate copy of local variables

well, not only threads. local variable have a scope of deceleration. when you get out of the scope (in this case the function) the local variable deleted. the next call will create new variables, meaning every call to the function will have different local variables, even if their value is the same

> Will there be two different copies of hashtable objects for two
>   different threads ?

i guess the answer is clear for you now, Yes, there will be different copies of `hashtable` for the different threads

Answer (score 1):

> Will there be two different copies of hashtable objects for two different threads ?.

Yes.

Each thread has its own stack created when you create the thread. That stack is not shared with other threads. 
Each time you invoke that method, a local variable is created for that specific thread( the hashtable itself will be created on objects heap, and the reference to this hashtable will be kept on stack).

For instance, if you call this method from 2 different threads, you'll end up with 2 HashTables on objects heap and 2 references on theirs threads stack.

Answer (score 1):

`parameterMap`, being local will be on the stack, although `new Hashtable<String,String>()` will create the Hashtable object on the heap, being pointed by your local variable `parameterMap`. So, each thread that runs as a light weight process, running in same process address space, sharing the global data, but separate stack, so separate local variables.
To share, you may declare `parameterMap` within your class as instance variable (if shared instances across threads) or class static variable.